# Using “help” instead of “please"

Tags: politeness

Some speakers use “help” instead of “please”:

- Can you help (to) confirm this?
- Can you help (to) send meeting notes?

To mean the same thing as:

- Can you please confirm this?
- Can you please send meeting notes?

What do you think about that usage?

Comment: You should summarize what you think they (help vs. please) mean. They don't mean the same thing, and context is needed to know which is better.

Comment: Edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The use of **please confirm** implies that you are asking for a simple statement of fact:

> Can you tell me if this is right?

But the use of **help to confirm** can mean that you are requesting actual *aid* in verifying something:

> Can you help me conduct this experiment so I can validate my theory?

In other words, there is a degree of context that's required between these two things.

---

The use of **please send** implies that you are asking somebody else to send something:

> Could you send these meeting notes for me?

But the use of **help to send** means that you are asking somebody to assist you with your own sending—or to join you in the activity:

> I can't figure out how to use this software. Can you help me send these meeting notes?

Again, context plays a key role.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **help** (to), it will sound like an unissued demand, but no serious demand; however, if you use **please**, it is more of a polite request to ask somebody to confirm/send meeting notes. But both will do, without anyone getting upset with you.

...and if you use **help**, it will imply that somebody has to help you to confirm something/send meeting notes because you cannot do it alone. If you say **please**, it will imply that it's not your job to do it, and you ask a person to do it instead of you. In context, the meaning of these two would surely be more clear.